# Symfony 2: Translations on dynamic data

Tags: symfony

in my user entity I have declared for example $body.
Then when I am getting the User Entity and in twig I can call user.body which will return atheltic, slim and etc. Using the translator I have declared the same variables:

```
slim: 'Slim'
athletic: 'Athletic'
```

and in my view I am calling it like this:

```
  <li>{{ user.body | trans({}, "profile") }}</li>
```

this works perfect but I would rather have my translator file be something like this:

```
body:    
  slim: 'Slim'
  athletic: 'Athletic'
```

if I say **profile.body** it doesn't call anything.

Comment: You could generate a translation key as a concatentated string and then translate that like `{{ ( 'body.' ~ user.body ) | trans({}, 'profile') }}`.

Answer (score 0):

From my previous experiences, I found it better to have the translation of business constants in a different file. This way you clearly separate the translation of your UI and the translation of your "data".

```
{{  'user.body.' ~ (user.body) | trans({}, 'business') }}
```